# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to do a clear command on Discord.js v14, but it keeps telling this error:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')
```

Here's the code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, Embed, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('clear')
        .setDescription("Delete messages")
        .addIntegerOption(option => option.setName('messages').setDescription('Messages to delete').setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const messages = interaction.options.getInteger('messages');
        
        if(!interaction.user.id.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageMessages)){
            interaction.reply({ content: "You can't send messages!", ephemeral: true} )
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`interaction.user.id` gives you a string containing the id of the user who ran the slash command. To check for the permissions, you need the `GuildMember` data of the user which you can access by using `interaction.member`. So, your fixed code would look like this:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, Embed, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('clear')
        .setDescription("Delete messages")
        .addIntegerOption(option => option.setName('messages').setDescription('Messages to delete').setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const messages = interaction.options.getInteger('messages');
        
        if(!interaction.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageMessages)){
            interaction.reply({ content: "You can't send messages!", ephemeral: true} )
        }
        
    }
}
```